# Export PC Name and Updates Needed from WSUS to CSV Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to export a CSV file from WSUS using PowerShell containing a list of all computers that need updates and the titles or KBs of the updates each particular computer needs.  Something like this...

Computer1, update1, update2

Computer2, update1, update3, update5

Computer3, update2, update4

I found this script on TechNet that returns the computer name and how many updates are needed, but it doesn't return the titles of the updates, and it may return all computers in WSUS, not just the ones that need updates (I'm in a test environment of only 1 computer right now).

```
Function Get-WSUSClientNeeded {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$WsusServer
    )
    #Load assemblies
    [void][system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration')
    #Connect to WSUS
    $Global:wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer($WsusServer,$False,8530)
    #Create Scope objects
    $computerscope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ComputerTargetScope
    $updatescope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope
    #Get Update Summary
    $wsus.GetSummariesPerComputerTarget($updatescope,$computerscope) | ForEach {
       New-Object PSObject -Property @{
           ComputerName = ($wsus.GetComputerTarget([guid]$_.ComputerTargetId)).FullDomainName
           NeededCount = ($_.DownloadedCount + $_.NotInstalledCount)
           DownloadedCount = $_.DownloadedCount
           NotApplicableCount = $_.NotApplicableCount
           NotInstalledCount = $_.NotInstalledCount
           InstalledCount = $_.InstalledCount
           FailedCount = $_.FailedCount
       }
    }
}

Get-WSUSClientNeeded -WsusServer 'Server' | Select ComputerName, NeededCount
```

I'm very new to PowerShell, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, what are the properties returned from `$wsus.GetSummariesPerComputerTarget($updatescope,$computerscope)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be much easier than expected.

```
Get-WindowsUpdate -WindowsUpdate
```

**Get-WindowsUpdate** will return available updates from an online source.  The **-WindowsUpdate** parameter will return the updates from WSUS.  Make sure to import the PSWindowsUpdate module first.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a custom-object from the results of the update summary. You're using piping and an inline loop.  These are complicated and while you may be able to improve your scripts using them later, getting them to work in the first place is much easier if you use loops and variable assignments and arrays.

My suggestion of how to work through this is to

1. Split the work part of that into an actual loop. (`$wsus.Get.... piped through foreach and creating objects)
2. Add the results of your pull command (the object you create) to an array.  You're creating an object then not doing anything with it.
3. Loop through the array and run commands against the elements.  Apply filters or extract info as you wish.
4. Only pull the properties you want.  Most `Get-` cmdlets include the -properties switch.
5. Use `Get-Members` to peek inside the objects returned by a command.  It will tell you the properties and methods of the object.

Run commands like this at the command line in ISE, figure out which property names you want to extract.

```
    $summaries = $wsus.GetSummariesPerComputerTarget($updatescope,$computerscope) 
    $summaries | get-members
```

loop through an array, pull out data, put it in another array

```
foreach (summary in $summaries) {
  $props = $summary | select property1, property2
  $AnswerArray += $props
  }
```

Export to a csv, or use the array of answers in the next stage

```
$AnswerArray | export-csv -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber -Path c:\temp\answers.csv
```

Most of my PowerShell experience is with Active Directory, but I would have one script to extract data into a CSV, manipulate that in another script, or outside PowerShell with other tools like excel, and use it as input in a script that makes the changes I needed to make.